Unexpected result of string concatenation in C
The following C program should append an "/" after the path received in argv if the argument does not end in "/". The "odd for me" behavior is that after the first iteration in the while loop, the full_path string is appended with the full_path from the first iteration. What I am thinking is that the memory is somehow reused but I don't have a sure explination for it and I was hoping someone would help me understand. I have the same behavior using threads but it errors on the third iteration since the memory needed is more than the memory allocated.
P.S. I am trying to learn how to work with strings and mostly with pointers in general in C.
Thank you in advance!
Code:
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *full_path();
typedef struct th_ar
{
    int argc;
    char **argv;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // pthread_t thread_id;
    while (1)
    {
        sleep(5);
        struct th_ar ta = {.argc = argc, .argv = argv};
        // pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, full_path, (void *)&ta);
        full_path((void *)&ta);
    }

    return 0;
}

void *full_path(void *args)
{
    struct th_ar *ta = (struct th_ar *)args;
    char *path = ta->argv[1];
    printf("path: %s\n", path);
    char *filename = "test.sh";
    char *full_path = (char *)malloc(strlen(path) + strlen(filename) + 2); // this is the correct way
    // char *full_path = (char *)malloc(strlen(path) + strlen(filename) + 4096);
    if (full_path == NULL)
        return (void *)1;
    strcpy(full_path, path);
    char last_char = path[strlen(path) - 1];
    if (last_char == '/')
    {
        // printf("%s\n", "It ends in /");
    }
    else
    {
        // printf("%s\n", "It does not end in /");
        // printf("%s\n", "Appending / at the end");
        full_path[strlen(full_path)] = '/';
    }
    strcat(full_path, filename);
    printf("full_path: %s\n", full_path);
    free(full_path);

    return (void *)0;
}


I have tried to execute the code but the behavior is not what I was expecting given I have experience in other programming languages that does not behave like this.
first iteration => /home/developer/folder/anotherfolder/test.sh
second iteratiom => /home/developer/folder/anotherfolder/test.shtest.sh

full_path[strlen(full_path)] = '/'; overwrites the 0 byte with a /. As a result, you no longer have a string, and passing full_path to strcat is not valid.

I'd suggest something like 'Unexpected result of string concatenation' for the title, because that is what you're experiencing. Function calls you do in a while loop work as they should.

Consider using snprintf() to build a string from component parts. Make the malloc() more generous, not down to the exact supposed length.

This line
full_path[strlen(full_path)] = '/';

'appends' the '/' character to the path, but it does not terminate the new version of a string with a zero byte.
It's undefined what happens next. Depending on your luck, the byte at the following position after the slash character may or may not be zero. As a result your string may coincidentally appear properly terminated, or it may get appended any text data (of an unpredictable length) which happened to remain in that area of memory, or it may get appended any garbage. Using such data will likely cause problems (for example, seeking the end of the string with any string-processing function may run past the end of allocated memory block and cause Invalid Memory Access).
To avoid that you should do
strcat(full_path,"/");

instead.
Or, if you love 'manual' string building:
size_t len = strlen(full_path);
full_path[len] = '/';
full_path[len+1] = 0;

Note the use of len variable—you must not call strlen() just after storing the '/' character, as you (may) have no string terminator at the moment, hence you need len to calculate len+1 for the string terminator.

This is even better if you amend it by explaining that without the null-terminator it no longer is a string, and passing it to any function which expects one invokes undefined behavior.

Another answer by CiaPan identifies the primary problem with your code — how you are misusing the string functions.
However, using strcat() is slow because it has to skip over the leading string before doing any copying.  You call strlen() four times in the code.  You should cache the lengths and then use memmove() (or memcpy()) to copy the data with known lengths.  This avoids rescanning the strings beyond calculating the length (one pass over each string) and copying the strings (a second pass over each string).
I chose to generalize the code to handle multiple path name arguments in a single invocation of the program.  I also chose to invert the return conditions from full_path(), returning NULL on failure and non-null on success.  The main program should check that there are pathname arguments before invoking the function, reporting the error on standard error and exiting with a failure status.  I also chose to iterate three times rather than sleeping and relying on an interrupt — I'm not fond of infinite loops.  Note that you should either define a name with typedef (e.g. typedef struct th_ar { … } th_ar;) or not use typedef at all.  Since the full_path() function uses struct th_ar, I removed the keyword typedef.
Putting all this into practice, you might come up with:
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* The struct th_ar is a prelude to using pthreads */
static void *full_path(void *);

struct th_ar
{
    int argc;
    char **argv;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s path [...]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        struct th_ar ta = {.argc = argc, .argv = argv};
        if (full_path(&ta) == 0)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void *full_path(void *args)
{
    struct th_ar *ta = (struct th_ar *)args;
    for (int i = 1; i < ta->argc; i++)
    {
        char *path = ta->argv[i];
        printf("path: %s\n", path);
        char *filename = "test.sh";
        size_t plen = strlen(path);
        size_t flen = strlen(filename);
        char *full_path = malloc(plen + flen + 2);
        if (full_path == NULL)
            return NULL;
        memmove(full_path, path, plen);
        size_t eos = plen;
        if (full_path[eos - 1] != '/')
            full_path[eos++] = '/';
        memmove(&full_path[eos], filename, flen + 1);
        printf("full_path: [%s]\n", full_path);
        free(full_path);
    }
    return args;    /* Non-null void pointer */
}

Even better would be to abstract the path concatenation code into a function that does no printing, and then calling that in a loop with printing in what is currently called full_path().  The new function should take the path as given and a file name as arguments.  It should also be made const-correct; it should not modify its arguments.  It's also not a particularly good idea to have a local variable full_path inside a function full_path.  It works OK, but (amongst other things) you can't make the code recursive because the local variable hides the function.
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* The struct th_ar is a prelude to using pthreads */
static void *path_printer(void *);
static char *full_path(const char *dirname, const char *filename);

struct th_ar
{
    int argc;
    char **argv;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s dirname [...]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        struct th_ar ta = {.argc = argc, .argv = argv};
        if (path_printer(&ta) == 0)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

static char *full_path(const char *dirname, const char *filename)
{
    size_t plen = strlen(dirname);
    size_t flen = strlen(filename);
    char *pathname = malloc(plen + flen + 2);
    if (pathname == NULL)
        return NULL;
    memmove(pathname, dirname, plen);
    size_t eos = plen;
    if (pathname[eos - 1] != '/')
        pathname[eos++] = '/';
    memmove(&pathname[eos], filename, flen + 1);
    return pathname;
}

static void *path_printer(void *args)
{
    struct th_ar *ta = (struct th_ar *)args;
    for (int i = 1; i < ta->argc; i++)
    {
        const char *dirname = ta->argv[i];
        printf("dirname:  [%s]\n", dirname);
        const char *filename = "test.sh";
        char *pathname = full_path(dirname, filename);
        if (pathname == NULL)
            return NULL;
        printf("fullpath: [%s]\n", pathname);
        free(pathname);
    }
    return args;    /* Non-null void pointer */
}

Example output (second program):
$ cat41 /home/developer/folder/anotherfolder /home/developer/folder/anotherfolder/ /short/path/ /very/much/longer/path/though/the/original/was/quite/long /abbreviated
dirname:  [/home/developer/folder/anotherfolder]
fullpath: [/home/developer/folder/anotherfolder/test.sh]
dirname:  [/home/developer/folder/anotherfolder/]
fullpath: [/home/developer/folder/anotherfolder/test.sh]
dirname:  [/short/path/]
fullpath: [/short/path/test.sh]
dirname:  [/very/much/longer/path/though/the/original/was/quite/long]
fullpath: [/very/much/longer/path/though/the/original/was/quite/long/test.sh]
dirname:  [/abbreviated]
fullpath: [/abbreviated/test.sh]
dirname:  [/home/developer/folder/anotherfolder]
fullpath: [/home/developer/folder/anotherfolder/test.sh]
dirname:  [/home/developer/folder/anotherfolder/]
fullpath: [/home/developer/folder/anotherfolder/test.sh]
dirname:  [/short/path/]
fullpath: [/short/path/test.sh]
dirname:  [/very/much/longer/path/though/the/original/was/quite/long]
fullpath: [/very/much/longer/path/though/the/original/was/quite/long/test.sh]
dirname:  [/abbreviated]
fullpath: [/abbreviated/test.sh]
dirname:  [/home/developer/folder/anotherfolder]
fullpath: [/home/developer/folder/anotherfolder/test.sh]
dirname:  [/home/developer/folder/anotherfolder/]
fullpath: [/home/developer/folder/anotherfolder/test.sh]
dirname:  [/short/path/]
fullpath: [/short/path/test.sh]
dirname:  [/very/much/longer/path/though/the/original/was/quite/long]
fullpath: [/very/much/longer/path/though/the/original/was/quite/long/test.sh]
dirname:  [/abbreviated]
fullpath: [/abbreviated/test.sh]

